# boto3 download_file() throws botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to download a file from AWS S3 using boto3. `download_file(bucket,file_key,name)` throws 403 Forbidden. I have access to the bucket not sure why I am getting 403 error.
When I try it with `boto-get_contents_to_filename()` it works fine I am able to download the file.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file(bucket,key,fileName)
```

Comment: s3.download_file(bucket, file_key, file_name) throws 403 Forbidden error

Comment: How have you set up the credentials for `boto3`, they are different from `boto`?

Comment: @Vinodhini the credentials you are using should have permissions for s3 ops you want to perform. `HeadObject` is one of those operations. If you are using your own account you can give the IAM user (or role) the `HeadObject` permission. You may need to give yourself other permissions too depending on what you want to do.